# I need help understanding this error message rubygem gosu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, libgosu

Im trying to run a simple gosu program written in ruby, but am having trouble getting gosu to function.
I am running Ruby through WSL Visual Studio Code on windows 11 if that helps.
I keep running into this error

```
harrisonm02@LAPTOP-7FCL2R59:/mnt/c/Users/harri/Documents/Uni/Semester 2/Intro to Programing/VSC/Music player$ ruby gosu.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from gosu.rb:2:in `<main>'
        1: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
/home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': cannot load such file -- gosu (LoadError)
        6: from gosu.rb:2:in `<main>'
        5: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:147:in `require'
        4: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:158:in `rescue in require'
        3: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:158:in `require'
        2: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gosu-1.4.3/lib/gosu.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
/home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0) - /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gosu-1.4.3/lib/gosu.so (LoadError)   
        7: from gosu.rb:2:in `<main>'
        6: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:147:in `require'
        5: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:158:in `rescue in require'
        4: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:158:in `require'
        3: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gosu-1.4.3/lib/gosu.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:147:in `require'
        1: from /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:158:in `rescue in require'
/home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:158:in `require': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0) - /home/harrisonm02/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gosu-1.4.3/lib/gosu.so (LoadError)
```

Here is the program im attepting to run

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gosu'


# The screen has layers: Background, middle, top
module ZOrder
  BACKGROUND, MIDDLE, TOP = *0..2
end

class DemoWindow < Gosu::Window
  def initialize
    super(640, 400, false)
  end

  def draw
    # see www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/Gosu/Color for colours
    draw_quad(0, 0, 0xff_ffffff, 640, 0, 0xff_ffffff, 0, 400, 0xff_ffffff, 640, 400, 0xff_ffffff, ZOrder::BACKGROUND)
    draw_quad(160, 240, 0xff_000000, 160, 220, 0xff_000000, 480, 240, 0xff_000000, 480, 220, 0xff_000000, ZOrder::TOP)
    draw_quad(170, 240, 0xff_000000, 190, 220, 0xff_000000, 170, 360, 0xff_000000, 190, 360, 0xff_000000, ZOrder::TOP)
    draw_quad(450, 240, 0xff_000000, 470, 220, 0xff_000000, 450, 360, 0xff_000000, 470, 360, 0xff_000000, ZOrder::TOP)
    draw_quad(210, 210, 0xff_000000, 270, 210, 0xff_000000, 210, 230, 0xff_000000, 270, 230, 0xff_000000, ZOrder::TOP)
    draw_quad(235, 180, 0xff_000000, 245, 180, 0xff_000000, 235, 230, 0xff_000000, 245, 230, 0xff_000000, ZOrder::TOP)
    draw_quad(190, 140, 0xff_000000, 290, 140, 0xff_000000, 190, 200, 0xff_000000, 290, 200, 0xff_000000, ZOrder::TOP)
    draw_quad(195, 145, 0xff_0000ff, 285, 145, 0xff_0000ff, 195, 195, 0xff_0000ff, 285, 195, 0xff_ffffff, ZOrder::TOP)
    draw_quad(440, 280, 0xff_808080, 400, 280, 0xff_808080, 440, 360, 0xff_808080, 400, 360, 0xff_808080, ZOrder::TOP)
   # draw_quad(410, 285, 0xff_00ff00, 405, 285, 0xff_00ff00, 410, 290, 0xff_00ff00, 405, 290, 0xff_00ff00, ZOrder::TOP)
    draw_triangle(415, 285, 0xff_00ff00, 405, 285, 0xff_00ff00, 410, 293, 0xff_00ff00, ZOrder::TOP)
    #img = Gosu::Image.new(Circle.new(10)) 
   # img.draw(410, 300, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
  end
end

DemoWindow.new.show
```

Comment: The error message means that there is no file named `gosu.rb` in the LOADPATH. You could do a `puts $:` immediately before the `require 'gosu'` to check this.

Comment: i think you dont have `gosu` gem installed. run ` gem install gosu ` first.  then try executing your script